# Exporting problem

Tags: import

So I exported this material( The one in the picture) for blender to unreal engine but when I exported the fbx file in ue4. When I applied the material to a plane well it was just a black material they was nothing showing up. Could someone help me please.
[image]

Comment: You can't export Blender's node based materials to a game engine like Unreal in a format like .fbx.

Comment: Well how should I do it because I really need it exported in ue4

Comment: The correct way of doing it, is baking the textures onto the low poly model and then setup a material with the *Principled BSDF*, a *Material Output* and otherwise just *Image Texture* nodes. Then export as glTF or fbx with copied/packed textures. Blender's node system is not the same as Unreal's, even the glTF format will not be able to transfer all of them. The other option is of course to recreate the material in Unreal using their shader editor.

Comment: I don't understant. But how would I do that

Comment: But I did this one In shading and i didn't use a texture. I followed a tutorial here is the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb81bSTygt4&list=WL&index=47&t=0s